# How to make the window behind a dialog not clickable?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

i want to set blocked the window behind dialog to prevent the user do click or modify any content of the window while the dialog are running, and when the user close de dialog then set unlocked the window behind dialog.

```
import gtk;
window = gtk.Window();
window.set_title("Window Behind Dialog");
window.set_default_size(426,240);
textentry = gtk.TextView();
window.add(textentry);
window.show_all();
dialog = gtk.Window();
dialog.set_title("Dialog");
dialog.set_default_size(256,144);
label = gtk.Label("Unlock the window behind when this dialog get close");
dialog.add(label);
dialog.show_all();
gtk.main();
```

Which method is used for it, in Gtk or PyGtk?, for example:

```
window.set_disabled_to_all_events();
```

or

```
window.set_disabled();
```

or

```
window.events_disabled(True);
```

or

```
window.set_blocked(True);
```

Comment: FYI: This being Python, you don't *need* to terminate statements with semicolon.

Comment: PyGTK is the name of the old static python bindings for GTK+ 2. Both have been deprecated for years. Don't waste time learning legacy stuff, and switch to GTK+ 3 dynamic bindings, using pygobject. Please read this tutorial: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 5):

If you have a window manager that honors modal windows, you could use `set_modal` on the dialog window.

If not, you could use `set_sensitive` on the parent window. Call this with `False` when the dialog is shown, and with `True` when the dialog is hidden or destroyed.

I've added Gtk3 examples below. I recommend that you switch to PyGObject and Python 3 before investing too much effort in a deprecated toolkit.

Modal window example:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window(title="Hello World")
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

window.add(Gtk.TextView())
window.show_all()

dialog = Gtk.Window(title="Dialog")
dialog.set_transient_for(window)
dialog.set_modal(True)
dialog.show()

Gtk.main()
```

Or using explicit `set_sensitive`:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window(title="Hello World")
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

window.add(Gtk.TextView())
window.show_all()

dialog = Gtk.Window(title="Dialog")
dialog.set_transient_for(window)
window.set_sensitive(False)

def destroy_cb(widget, data):
    data.set_sensitive(True)

dialog.connect("destroy", destroy_cb, window)
dialog.show()

Gtk.main()
```